# Simple Evaluation to run a step once a week only?

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to run a Job that, if it is the first time running the Job this week, it will go trough an extra step. I found that I can do this evalution with Simple Evaluation but I can't find how to make this 'once a week'check.

Anyone have any idea how can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

do this

create new transformation, use get System info step and in type, select "first day of this week", check your date with this column and if equal, run your main using job executor else run the other one.